# Unity3d and building WebGL (Unable to load DLL 'QCARWrapper') [Vuforia]

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, unity-webgl

When i'm trying build project to WebGL and run in a browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox), i got an error:

```
DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'QCARWrapper': The specified module could not be found.
```

[image: unity webgl error vuforia]

QCARWrapper in project exists:

[image: unity project]

Comment: I don't think vuforia is meant to work on webgl.

Comment: What about Unity Web Player?

Comment: Same. Vuforia does iOS android and no more. Not even windows phone. You can debug in OS X/Windows editor but no build for those platform.

Comment: @fafase Many thanks!